# Utilizar context dentro de onClick

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Estoy intentando referirme a un método de mi clase `ButtonsHandlersActivity` dentro del Listener `onClick`, sin embargo me dice que no encuentra el método.

Éste es el error de compilación:

> error: method callInClickListenerCustom in class
>   ButtonsHandlersActivity cannot be applied to given types;

Esta es la porción de código

```
private void addListener(Button myDinamicButton)
{
            myDinamicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public  void onClick(View v) {
                    //Context c = getApplicationContext();
                    Context c = ButtonsHandlersActivity.this;
                    (ButtonsHandlersActivity) c.callInClickListenerCustom();
                }
            });
}

public void callInClickListenerCustom()
{
     // este es el método que intento llamar
}
```

Comment: has intentado usar, `getContext()`, o `getAplicationContext()`? en vez de crear ese contexto allí?

Comment: Si, por eso tengo comentado el getAplicationContext justo arriba, el error es el mismo, me dice que no encuentra el metodo aunque le haga un cast a (ButtonsHandlersActivity)

Comment: Asumo que eso lo haces o lo intentas hacer desde un fragment, no? intentaste esto? private Activity activity; ---- activity.callInClickListenerCustom();

Comment: Lo acabo de chquear tal cual me lo pasas, pero me tira error de compilación "error: illegal start of expression". 
 public  void onClick(View v) { private Activity activity; activity.callInClickListenerCustom(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ButtonsHandlersActivity` hereda de `Activity` lo que hace un `Context`  pero `Context` no tiene un metodo `callInClickListenerCustom`.

Utiliza la instancia directa de la clase `ButtonsHandlersActivity` para acceder al metodo definido en la clase:

```
ButtonsHandlersActivity.this.callInClickListenerCustom();
```

O encierra la operacion de casteo dentro de parentesis para que puedas acceder al tipo `ButtonsHandlersActivity` y a la vez al metodo:

```
Context c = ButtonsHandlersActivity.this;
((ButtonsHandlersActivity)c).callInClickListenerCustom();
```

O en vez de utilizar el tipo `Context`, utilizas el tipo real del activity en la variable `c`:

```
ButtonsHandlersActivity c = ButtonsHandlersActivity.this;
c.callInClickListenerCustom();
```

O simplemente llamas al metodo ya que el evento esta en la misma clase:

```
myDinamicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public  void onClick(View v) {
                   callInClickListenerCustom();
                }
});
```

---

Nota: de todas te recomiendo la ultima.

Comment: es la falta de experiencia... gracias
Estaba haciendo this.callInClickListenerCustom();, pero el context de this es el handler, no se me ocurrio llamar derecho al método sin pasarle el this.